# Dart immutability

Tags: dart, flutter

```
AuthState copy({
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser,
    String token,

    List<Map> contracts,
    bool loadingContracts,
    String contractsError,

    List<Map> searchModules,
    bool loadingSearchModules,
    String searchModulesError
  }) {
    AuthState state = new AuthState(
        firebaseUser ??= this.firebaseUser,

        token ??= this.token,

        contracts ??= this.contracts,
        loadingContracts ??= this.loadingContracts,
        contractsError ??= this.contractsError,

        searchModules ??= this.searchModules,
        loadingSearchModules ??= this.loadingSearchModules,
        searchModulesError ??= this.searchModulesError
    );
```

I am using Redux so every time a action is dispatched you need to create a new state.

When I use `??` and not provide a parameter the value will be set to null, so that is not what I want.
If I use `??=` it will assign object's property to the new value.
But it is unable to set to value to null when I explicitly set the param to `null`.

I am walking around with this problem for a few days now. Would be amazing if someone could help me.

Btw I am building a Flutter app with https://github.com/alexeieleusis/greencat as Redux library.

Answer (score 1):

Dart doesn't provide a way to distinguish whether `null` was passed explicitely to an optional parameter, or if no parameter was passed at all.

You can use something like

```
AuthState.copy({A a = someDummyValue /* other parameters}) {
  AuthState state = new AuthState(
    a == someDummyValue ? this.a : a,
    /* similar for other parameters */
  )
```

Where someDummyValue has to be defined somewhere like

```
static const someDummyValue = const A.dummy();
```

This only works if all fields in `A` are `final`, otherwise you'll have to find another way to make a unique `someDummyValue`.

I'd suggest to use the [built_value](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/built_value) package to generate the code for immutable classes with builders and serializers.